# Comment length validation message

Tags: bug, comments

As I understand, SO removes name of the OP from the comment if OP and you are the only participants in comment discussion so far. This can lead to somewhat confusing situations like this:

[image: comments bug]

Message contains 18 (including space in between), and yet validation message says that it's not even 15. I am guessing this is because the `@user...` part is removed before validation happens, but there is no clear sign of this anywhere. Looks like a very-very minor, but still bug.

Comment: Not so much a bug as a misrepresented feature, I'd say. The feature being that the user reference is stripped when testing for comment length.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, do you mean it "is stripped when testing for comment length" for all comments? Or just for comments where the addressee is obvious, like above?

Comment: I don't know; but the addressee *syntax* is always obvious to the server when using `@` symbol, so presumably it'll be stripped wherever in the comment it is.